# How can I fetch data from external into my web api?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to fetch data from https://reqres.in/api/users/ into my web API. What solution can I solve?

```
public class users
{   
    public users(int ID, string url)
    {
        id = ID;
    }

    public int id { get; set; }

    public string email { get; set; }

    public string first_name { get; set; }

    public string last_name { get; set; }

    public string avatar { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow. 
what have you ***tried yourself*** so far? what problems did you encounter? what have you researched? please **edit** your question to include more information. i recommend [taking the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), as well as reading [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [what's on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: You'll also want to take a look at [how to make a HTTP request in C#](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/console-webapiclient)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think something like this should work. Using Newtonsoft and RestSharp

```
using RestSharp;
using Newtonsoft.Json;


var client = new RestClient("https://reqres.in/api/users/");
var request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);

var aqq = client.Execute(request).Content;
dynamic json = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(aqq);

Users users = new();

foreach (var user in json["data"])
{
   users.id = user["id"];
   users.email = user["email"];
   users.first_name = user["first_name"];
   users.last_name = user["last_name"];
   users.avatar = user["avatar"];
}
```

EDIT: Like Peter pointed out in comments section, it will overwrite users and contain only last entry. I think better solution is to use List<Users>, like:

```
List<Users> users = new();

foreach (var user in json["data"])
{
   users.Add(new Users(id = user["id"], email = user["email"], first_name = user["first_name"], last_name = user["last_name"], avatar = user["avatar"]));
}
```

Comment: This solution overwrites the `users` variable **5 times** and will contain the user where the id is 6.

Comment: @PeterCsala I corrected my answer, I hope it's better this time :)

Comment: Yepp, that's better :)